# Formula for $U(N)$ integration wanted

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

Before you jump on the "duplicate" buttom, let me say that I do not want to hear about Weingarten calculus and I do not want to see a character of the symmetric group.

What I would like is a formula for the (normalized) Haar measure integral
$$
\int_{U(N)} g_{i_1 j_1}\cdots g_{i_n j_n} {\bar{g}}_{k_1 l_1}\cdots {\bar{g}}_{k_n l_n}\ d\mu(g)
$$
of the form
$$
\left.\mathcal{D}\ g_{i_1 j_1}\cdots g_{i_n j_n} {\bar{g}}_{k_1 l_1}\cdots {\bar{g}}_{k_n l_n}\right|_{g=\bar{g}=0}
$$
where $\mathcal{D}$ is an explicit constant coefficient differential operator of infinite order.
Of course, in this formula the $g$'s and $\bar{g}$'s are treated are $2N^2$ completely unrelated formal variables.

As an example of what I would like, in the case of $SU(N)$ and $\bar{g}$-free monomials
$$
\mathcal{D}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{0!1!\cdots (N-1)!}{n!(n+1)!\cdots(n+N-1)!}\ ({\rm det}(\partial g))^n
$$
works.

As per the "Additional remark" in my second answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255492/how-to-constructively-combinatorially-prove-schur-weyl-duality), I had a vague recollection of seeing a math-physics paper with
such a formula, but maybe my memory is faulty. So I think it's better to ask the experts.

Comment: I remember this https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9209083v2.pdf but the difference is that instead of the Haar measure there is an Itsykson-Zuber exponent, too. Then however you can apply differential operator to M or N to get "correlation functions" and then set M=N=0. Is that helpful?

Comment: :)- why ask on MO when I could have walked down the hallway and knocked on your door...Thanks this looks really interesting.

Comment: :) the paper does not use differential operators but with them the statement hopefully can be obtained easier. I have not checked details though.

Comment: and here https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0502041.pdf in introduction there is some discussion 10 years later

Comment: Still worth adding a formal answer to this question, even if it's been sorted!

Comment: @David: Although Leo's references are interesting in connection to my question, the latter has not been sorted unfortunately.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam ok, fair enough.

Comment: @Leo: you should as David said write your comments as an answer that I will definitely upvote. I did not yet have time to look at Shatashvili's article in detail. But, it seems that what I need is an explicit result for the limit of the integral of $R(m)\Delta(M))$ when $M\rightarrow 0$ and of course $N$ is set to zero. In any case your pointer to this paper is very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on my comments, this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9209083v2.pdf by Shatashvili deals
with ``correlation functions'' of Haar unitary matrices of the form
$$
\int_{U(N)}^{} d\mu(U) e_{}^{tr(UAU_{}^{-1}B)}
U_{i_1j_1}^{}\bar U_{k_1\ell_1}^{}\ldots 
U_{i_mj_m}^{}\bar U_{k_m\ell_m},
$$
and provides a certain combinatorial formula for these. Then setting $A=0$ would probably
recover what you're asking about.

The same correlation functions (and an alternative formula for them) are also discussed in 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0502041.pdf