# Reference for exponential Vandermonde determinant identity

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, combinatorial-identities

I recently stumbled upon the following identity, valid for any real numbers $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ and $\lambda_{n1} \leq \dots \leq \lambda_{nn}$:

$$ \mathrm{det}( e^{\alpha_i \lambda_{nj}} )_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} = V(\alpha) \int_{GT_\lambda} \exp( \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \lambda_{ij} (\alpha_{n+1-i}-\alpha_{n-i}))$$
where $V(\alpha)$ is the Vandermonde determinant
$$ V(\alpha) := \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} (\alpha_j - \alpha_i),$$
$GT_\lambda$ is the Gelfand-Tsetlin polytope of tuples $(\lambda_{ij})_{1 \leq j \leq i < n}$ obeying the interlacing relations $\lambda_{i+1,j} \leq \lambda_{i,j} \leq \lambda_{i,j+1}$ and with the usual Lebesgue measure, and one has the convention $\alpha_0 := 0$.  Thus for instance when $n=1$ one has
$$ e^{\alpha_1 \lambda_{11}} = \exp( \lambda_{11} \alpha_1 )$$
when $n=2$ one has
$$ \mathrm{det} \begin{pmatrix} e^{\alpha_1 \lambda_{21}} & e^{\alpha_1 \lambda_{22}} \\ e^{\alpha_2 \lambda_{21}} & e^{\alpha_2 \lambda_{22}} \end{pmatrix} $$
$$= (\alpha_2 - \alpha_1) \int_{\lambda_{21} \leq \lambda_{11} \leq \lambda_{22}} \exp( \lambda_{11} (\alpha_2-\alpha_1) + \lambda_{21} \alpha_1 + \lambda_{22} \alpha_1 )\ d\lambda_{11}$$
and when $n=3$ one has
$$ \mathrm{det} \begin{pmatrix} e^{\alpha_1 \lambda_{31}} & e^{\alpha_1 \lambda_{32}} & e^{\alpha_1 \lambda_{33}} \\ e^{\alpha_2 \lambda_{31}} & e^{\alpha_2 \lambda_{32}} & e^{\alpha_2 \lambda_{33}} \\ e^{\alpha_3 \lambda_{31}} & e^{\alpha_3 \lambda_{32}} & e^{\alpha_3 \lambda_{33}} \end{pmatrix} $$
$$ = (\alpha_2 - \alpha_1) (\alpha_3 - \alpha_1) (\alpha_3 - \alpha_2) \int_{\lambda_{31} \leq \lambda_{21} \leq \lambda_{32}} \int_{\lambda_{32} \leq \lambda_{22} \leq \lambda_{33}} \int_{\lambda_{21} \leq \lambda_{11} \leq \lambda_{22}}$$
$$ \exp( \lambda_{11} (\alpha_3-\alpha_2) + \lambda_{21} (\alpha_2-\alpha_1) + \lambda_{22} (\alpha_2-\alpha_1) + \lambda_{31} \alpha_1 + \lambda_{32} \alpha_1 + \lambda_{33} \alpha_1)$$
$$ d \lambda_{11} d\lambda_{22} d\lambda_{21},$$
and so forth.

The identity can be proven easily by induction.  I first discovered it by starting with the Schur polynomial identity
$$ \mathrm{det}( x_j^{a_i} )_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} = V(x) \sum_T x^{|T|}$$
where $0 \leq a_1 < \dots < a_n$ are natural numbers in increasing order, $T$ ranges over column-strict Young tableaux of shape $a_n-n+1, \dots, a_2-1, a_1$ with entries in $1,\dots,n$, and $x^{|T|} := x_1^{c_1} \dots x_n^{c_n}$ where $c_i$ is the number of occurrences of $i$ in $T$, and taking a suitable "continuum limit" as the $a_i$ go to infinity and the $x_j$ go to one in a particular fashion.  It can also be derived from the [Duistermaat-Heckmann formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duistermaat%E2%80%93Heckman_formula) for the Fourier transform of [Schur-Horn measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem), combined with the fact that this measure is the pushforward of Lebesgue measure on the Gelfand-Tsetlin polytope under a certain linear map.

Note that the identity also provides an immediate proof that any $n$ distinct exponential functions on $n$ distinct real numbers are linearly independent.

I am certain that this formula already appears in the literature, and perhaps even has a standard name, but I was unable to locate it with standard searches.  So my question here is if anyone recognizes the formula and can supply a reference for it.

Comment: Maybe related : https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1073960/FULLTEXT02.pdf

Comment: It looks close to the Harish-Chandra--Itzykson-Zuber identity, using the fact (Baryshnikov) that picking a random point in the GT${}_\lambda$ polytope is equivalent to picking a Haar-random Hermitian matrix with spectrum $\lambda_n$ and then taking its "principal minors" -- i.e., the  spectra of its top-left square submatrices...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This looks like a special case of a formula by Samson Shatashvili related to the HCIZ integral as mentioned in Ryan's answer. Compare, in particular the two ways of computing $\langle 1\rangle$ given by Equations 3.2 and 3.4 in ["Correlation Functions in The Itzykson-Zuber Model"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9209083) (thanks to Leonid Petrov for letting me know about this reference in his answer to this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256066/formula-for-un-integration-wanted)).

Comment: Pity I can't accept both answers.  I've accepted this one as it is an earlier reference that explicitly states two identities which, when combined, give the identity stated in the post.

Comment: @TerryTao: Indeed, it's too bad MO does not allow multiple accepted answers (as far as I know). BTW the paper by Shatashvili mentions earlier work with Alexeev and Faddeev but it's behind a paywall and I don't have access. It could be that your identity is there too.

Answer (score 17):

Write $\beta = \lambda_n$, the top row of your GT patterns.  It's a theorem of [Baryshnikov] that if we choose a uniformly random point in the polytope GT${}_\lambda$, it's equivalent to choosing a Haar-random Hermitian matrix with spectrum $\beta$ and then taking its "principal minors".  (I've also seen this fact credited to Weyl, and others.)  More precisely, let $B = \mathrm{diag}(\beta)$, and form a matrix $X = U B U^\dagger$, where $U$ is a random unitary.  Then let $\lambda_{11}$ be the top-left entry of $X$, let $\lambda_{21}, \lambda_{22}$ be the eigenvalues of the top-left $2 \times 2$ submatrix of $X$, ..., and let $\lambda_{n1}, \dots, \lambda_{nn}$ be the eigenvalues of the top-left $n \times n $ submatrix of $X$ (namely, $\beta$).  Then $\lambda$ is uniformly random in the polytope GT${}_\lambda$.

This probability distribution on $\lambda$ is basically your integral, but we have to divide by the volume of the polytope, which is $V(\lambda)/[(n-1)! (n-2)! \cdots 2! 1!]$.  I guess this is standard?  If not, it's also in Baryshnikov.

Having done so, your identity is the Harish-Chandra--Itzykson--Zuber identity applied to the matrices $A = \mathrm{diag}(\alpha)$ and $B$.  This follows by inferring the diagonal entries of $X$ from the Gelfand-Tsetlin pattern $\lambda$, which you can do because the Gelfand--Tsetlin pattern gives you the traces of all the top-left submatrices.

(By the way, I think the [Faraut] paper referenced below has a good exposition of some related things.)

*Baryshnikov, Yu.*, [**GUEs and queues**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s004400000101), Probab. Theory Relat. Fields 119, No.2, 256-274 (2001). [ZBL0980.60042](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0980.60042).

*Faraut, Jacques*, [**Rayleigh theorem, projection of orbital measures and spline functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/apam-2015-5012), Adv. Pure Appl. Math. 6, No. 4, 261-283 (2015). [ZBL1326.15058](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1326.15058).

Comment: I can't believe I had forgotten about the HCIZ formula, since I actually blogged about it: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/the-harish-chandra-itzykson-zuber-integral-formula/ .  I'm pretty sure though that the observation that the spectra of minors of a random element of a U(n) coadjoint orbit are distributed uniformly within the GT polytope is much older than Baryshnikov, though.

Comment: Quite possible, yes, though people do often cite Baryshnikov.  Olshanksi discusses it a bit briefly here -- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.7116.pdf -- and says it appears 'hidden' in Gelfand-Naimark'57.  This paper of O'Connell -- https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4849 -- calls it "well-known", but cites Baryshnikov.