# Linear independence of exponential functions: a reference

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is there a publication containing this obvious fact: For any real $T>0$, any natural $n$, any complex $c_1,\dots,c_n$, and any distinct complex $z_1,\dots,z_n$ such that $\sum_1^n c_k e^{tz_k}=0$ for all $t\in[0,T)$, we have $c_1=\dots=c_n=0$?

Somehow, I cannot find such a publication.

Comment: Vandermonde matrix is nonsingular?

Comment: Ycart, Bernard (2013), "A case of mathematical eponymy: the Vandermonde determinant", Revue d'Histoire des Mathématiques, 13, arXiv:1204.4716

Comment: You will probably find no 20 century publication, except an exercise is some Calculus or Linear algebra book. All these facts were really clarified in 18th century (perhaps by Wronski himself, or Vandermonde), but at that time they did not speak of "linear independence":-)

Comment: @ZachTeitler : Thank you for your comment. However, I don't need a proof -- only a reference.

Comment: @yarchik : Thank you for your comment. However, I cannot find this fact in that paper by Ycart.

Comment: Publication includes textbooks by definition, so it should definitely appear in several of them... I searched Google books [linear independence exponentials] and immediately got this reference: https://books.google.fr/books?id=Y3YSCmWBVwoC&pg=PA618&dq=linear+independence+exponentials&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzo8bZ-rbpAhVID2MBHX_jAXEQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=linear%20independence%20exponentials&f=false

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Thank you for your comment. A reference to a textbook would be fine.

Comment: @YCor : Thank you for your comment. This may help.

Comment: I put this question on my final exam for linear algebra, and I got oodles of cool very different proofs.  :-)

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: You may combine probl. 2, and problem 60,  of the second volume of Polya Szego, Problems and theorems of Analysis, part 7 "Determinants and Quadratic forms" (The first problem is Vandermonde det, the second is the criterion of linear independence).

Comment: See Lemma 3.2 p. 92 in  the book *Differential Equations*, Springer Verlag, 2016 by Viorel Barbu. The very elegant proof there  is not the usual proof based on Wronskians. He proves a bit more, namely that the exponentials are linearly independent over the field of rational functions  with complex coefficients.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Thank you for your latter comment as well. Unfortunately, I don't have the Pólya--Szego book right now. Do they include the case of complex $z_k$ as well?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu : Thank you for your comment. This is exactly what I needed except that in Barbu's Lemma 3.2 the linear independence is for the exponential functions defined on $\mathbb R$ rather than on a finite nonzero-length interval. However, the proof (which seems the most natural to me and which I had foremost in mind) will of course work for the finite-interval case as well. Would you like to present your comment as a formal answer?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: It does not matter that $z_k$ are complex: computation of the Vandermonde determinant holds for any field. Frankly speaking I do not understand your difficulty. Polya Szego can be found on line.

Comment: @IosifPinelis  Glad it helps. I'll keep  my answer  as a comment. My contribution is minimal

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : I have been unable to find the Pólya--Szego book online; could you please give a link to it? As for complex $z_k$'s and otherwise, my biggest concern is about how ready-to-use the published result is. As I said in the post and a comment, the desired result is obvious and the simplest and most natural proof (for me) is this: "divide by $e^{tz_n}$, differentiate in $t$, and use induction on $n$. $\Box$" -- without using Vandermonde determinants.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Yet another proof, of a stronger result -- with $t$ in an $n$-set rather than in an interval but only for real $z_k$'s -- is given on p. 10 of "Tchebycheff systems: with applications in analysis and statistics" by Karlin and Studden. That proof uses Rolle's theorem and thus does not seem to work for complex $z_k$'s.

Comment: Apostol's Calculus book has a proof; I believe it is at the beginning of volume 2.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo : Thank you for your comment. You are probably referring to Example 7 on page 10 of Section 1.7 of of the book at shorturl.at/cjwxZ . However, the proof there works only for for real $z_k$'s.

Comment: somewhat related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277655/reference-for-exponential-vandermonde-determinant-identity

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam : Thank you for pointing out to this connection.

Answer (score 6):

I will recount the more general statement of linear independence of characters, given in Lang's Algebra book, and credited to Artin. Let $G$ be a group, and $K$ a field. Then distinct homomorphisms $\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n: G \to K^\times$ are linearly independent.

**Proof:** Suppose not, and suppose we have a nontrivial linear relation

$$a_1 \phi_1 + \ldots + a_n \phi_n = 0,\qquad (1)$$

where $n$ is taken as small as possible. Clearly $n>1$ and $a_i \neq 0$ for all $i$. Because the $\phi_i$ are distinct, we can find an element $g \in G$ such that $\phi_1(g) \neq \phi_2(g)$. We have

$$a_1 \phi_1(gh) + a_2 \phi_2(gh) + \ldots + a_n \phi_n(gh) = 0$$

for all $h \in G$; by virtue of the $\phi_i$ being homomorphisms, this may be rewritten to say

$$a_1 \phi_1(g)\phi_1 + a_2 \phi_2(g)\phi_2 + \ldots + a_n \phi_n(g)\phi_n = 0, \qquad (2)$$

Dividing $(2)$ by $\phi_1(g)$ and then subtracting (1) from the result, we arrive at a linear relation

$$\left(a_2 \frac{\phi_2(g)}{\phi_1(g)} - a_2\right) \phi_2 + \ldots = 0$$

which has fewer than $n$ summands and is nontrivial by choice of $g$, contradiction. $\Box$

Comment: [K.Conrad quotes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/linearchar.pdf) E. Artin's "Galois theory" (1948).

Comment: This is very nice, cleaner than the differentiation. Also, (1) does not have to be assumed to hold over all $G$. At least in the case when $G=\mathbb R$, it is enough to assume that (1) holds over a neighborhood of $0$ -- which is what I need.

Comment: Right, I'm downvoted because why? This was a reference request.

Comment: @ToddTrimble : I don't see a reason for the downvote. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y_k(t)=e^{tz_k}$. Proving by contradiction, suppose that they are linearly dependent, that is 
$$\sum_{k=1}^nc_ky_k\equiv 0.$$
Differentiating $n-1$ times we obtain a homogeneous system of linear equations with respect to $c_k$. To have a non-trivial solution,
this system must have non-zero determinant. The determinant is: 
$$\left|\begin{array}{cccc}y_1&y_2&\ldots& y_n\\
y_1^\prime& y_2^\prime&\ldots&y_n^\prime\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
y_1^{(n-1)}& y_2^{(n-1)}&\ldots& y_n^{(n-1)}\end{array}\right|=A(t)
\left|\begin{array}{cccc}1&1&\ldots&1\\ z_1&z_2&\ldots& z_n\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
z_1^{n-1}&z_2^{n-1}&\ldots&z_n^{n-1}\end{array}\right|,$$
where $A(t)=e^{t(z_1+\ldots+z_n)}\neq 0$.
The determinant in the right hand side is easy to compute.
Consider it as a polynomial with respect to, $z_n$. It is evidently
of degree $n-1$ and has $n-1$ roots at $z_1,\ldots,z_{n-1}$.
Therefore it is of the corm $$C(z_1,\ldots,z_{n-1})(z_n-z_1)\ldots(z_n-z_{n-1}).$$ 
Looking at the top degree term, we conclude that $C$ is a similar polynomial. So by induction our determinant is
$$\prod_{i<k}(z_i-z_k).$$
this is never zero, since $z_k$ are distinct.

References. Polya Szego, Problems and theorems of analysis, vol II, Part 7, "Determinants and quadratic forms''. Computation of the Vandermonde determinant is problem 2. The Wronskian criterion of linear independence is problem 60.

Remark. Vandermondes's determinant is computed in 
ANY undergraduate textbook of
linear algebra, as a first example of determinant. For example, I teach linear algebra with the textbook of Strang, and differential equations with
the textbook of Boyce and di Prima. Both of them have Vandermonde determinant.

Remark 2. Undergraduate textbooks are rarely freely available online. If you insist on a free online reference, you may refer on the proof above.

Comment: In my experience, in 99% of the claimed applications of the Vandermonde determinant, one does not actually need the determinant, but only on the fact that the Vandermonde matrix is invertible, and this can be proved directly with a simpler argument: if a row vector is in the left kernel of this matrix, then its entries form the coefficients of a degree-$(n-1)$ polynomial with $n$ distinct zeros.

Comment: @Federico Poloni: I agree with this remark.