# Average of product of matrix elements in the special orthogonal group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, random-matrices

Given two lists $i$ and $j$ of $2n$ positive integers less than $N$, Collins and Sniady have computed, in [Integration with respect to the Haar measure on unitary, orthogonal and symplectic group](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0402073) (see also [On some properties of orthogonal Weingarten functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5143) by Collins and Matsumoto), the integral over the orthogonal group,
$$ \int_{O(N)} \prod_{k=1}^{2n}u_{i_kj_k}du=\sum_{\sigma,\tau}\Delta_\sigma(i)\Delta_\tau(j) {\rm Wg}_N(\sigma^{-1}\tau),\qquad (1)$$ where the sum is over matchings, $\Delta_\sigma(i)=1$ if and only if the sequence $i$ satisfies the matching $\sigma$ and ${\rm Wg}_N$ is called the Weingarten function.

This implies for instance that $\int_{O(N)} u_{11}u_{22}du=0$ because the list $(1,2)$ does not match.

On the other hand, we know that a matrix from $SO(2)$ is of the form $u=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \\
  \end{pmatrix}$ so clearly we have $\int_{SO(2)} u_{11}u_{22}du=1/2$. This shows that the $SO(N)$ result can be quite different from the $O(N)$ one.

Is there a general theory of integrals like (1) over $SO(N)$?

Comment: you can of course multiply the integrand by the factor $1+{\rm det}\,u$ to constrain the average over $O(N)$ to $SO(N)$; I have used this approach in App.B of arXiv:1012.0932 for a particular problem in the context of topological superconductivity.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question. This is not quite an answer  but a bit long for a comment.

A quick remark is that for $N$ odd a Haar-random element of $O(N)$ can be obtained as $\epsilon U$ where $\epsilon=\pm1$ with equal probability, and $U$ is a Haar-random element of $SO(N)$. So if your monomial has an even number of factors the integrals over $O(N)$ and $SO(N)$ coincide and thus Weingarten calculus is applicable. This is of course because for $N$ odd $-I$ has determinant $-1$ and is in the center of $O(N)$. I don't know if there is a similar trick for $N$ even.

I said it is a good question because, when looking at the vast probability/representation theory literature, I didn't see much as far an analogue of Weingarten calculus for special groups. Even the work of Chatterjee (and Basu and Ganguly,...) on $SO(N)$ lattice gauge theories does not seem to use Weingarten calculus. So for $SO(N)$, my answer to the question is: I don't know. However, for $SU(N)$ there is a combinatorial calculus. It is explained in my two answers to

[How to constructively/combinatorially prove Schur-Weyl duality?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255492/how-to-constructively-combinatorially-prove-schur-weyl-duality?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This technique was worked out explicitly by [Creutz](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.523581) but it has its roots in the work of Clebsch and Hilbert in invariant theory. See for example, the averaging operator $[\cdot]$ used by Hilbert on p. 523 of ["Ueber die Theorie der algebraischen Formen"](https://eudml.org/doc/157506) is basically the same as Creutz's formula for $SU(2)$. Also note that if a combinatorial Weingarten-like calculus for $SO(N)$ is perhaps missing, there is at least an Euler angle parametrization due to [Hurwitz](https://eudml.org/doc/58378) (see [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.09229) by Diaconis and Forrester).

Comment: Thank you for your input. The idea of working with explicit Euler angles seems scary. Let me point out that it is easy to derive the Weingarten function for $O(N)$ using the theory of zonal polynomials, as I show here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2182.  Zonal polynomials appear because of the relation $\int_{O(N)}s_{2\lambda}(Au)du=Z_\lambda(A^TA)/Z_\lambda(1)$, where $s$ is a Schur function. So a Weingarten calculus for $SO(N)$ might follow from the integral  $\int_{SO(N)}s_{\lambda}(Au)du$. Is this integral known?